# Unable to find element that looks like it's dynamically generated

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to find the email address text located in the below URL. You can clearly see the email address but I believe the text is generated dynamically through Javascript/React. When I copy the XPATH or CSS Selector and try to find the element like I would any other element I just get an error saying the element cannot be found.

I've tried time.sleep(30) to give the page time to fully load but that's not the issue.

I've tried:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mount_0_0_D8"]/div/div[1]/div/div[5]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/ul/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/span')
```

You can see from the snippet below that the email is visible but is between some ::before and ::after text I've not seen before.
[image: Inspect snippet]

https://www.facebook.com/homieestudio

Any ideas on how to consistently pull back the email address here? I'm using Chromedriver.

Comment: Do you want to share your code with us so we have some idea what's going on?

Comment: Added an image and the code I have tried, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the `email` address using the below

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@dir='auto'][contains(text(), 'info@homieestudio.co.uk')]")))
```

***OR***

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@dir='auto'][contains(text(), 'info@homieestudio.co.uk')]")))
```

***IMPORT***

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thanks for this, and if the email address was unknown would I just change the 'info@homieestudio.co.uk' to something like '@' and that would pull back any text with an @ symbol on the page? Might run into problems pulling back an email address somewhere else on the page I guess?

Comment: Yes, coz this code is to locate the specific email address, if you want to extract it, you can follow the solution provided by @undetected Selenium in the answer

Answer (score 1):

The clue is, the *Email Address* will always have the **@** sign.

---

### Solution

To extract the text ***Info@homieestudio.co.uk*** ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *XPATH* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.facebook.com/homieestudio')
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(., '@')]"))).text)
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and `get_attribute("textContent")`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.facebook.com/homieestudio')
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(., '@')]"))).get_attribute("textContent"))
  ```
- Console output:

  ```
  Info@homieestudio.co.uk
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55241232/7429447)